# Get unique items in a column starting with a given string

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, sorting

Consider a column with its unique values:

```
df['something'].unique() =array(['aa','bb','a','c']).
```

Now I want to know which of the items start with an a . 
My expected answer is

```
'aa','a'
```

Answer (score 6):

I think here is the simplest use of list comprehension with filtering:

```
out = [x for x in df['something'].unique() if x.startswith('a')]
print (out)
['aa', 'a']
```

For pandas solution use:

```
s = pd.Series(df['something'].unique())
out = s[s.str.startswith('a')].tolist()
print (out)
['aa', 'a']
```